# Trouble enqueueing jquery with custom theme

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I am in the process of learning WordPress/web development and have reached yet another hurdle. I cannot seem to load jquery as a dependency for a script. As I understand, jquery is already included with wordpress, but I cannot seem to get scripts to work, with errors in the browser console such as: Uncaught reference error: jquery is not defined at... . I would appreciate any guidance and I was hoping someone could explain the correct process of enqueueing or registering (still unaware of difference between the two) jquery, and correct me as to what i am doing wrong. I am new to programming in general and any advice would be a huge help.

The code I have so far is as follows:

//make a function to load scripts

```
function palpa_script_enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('materializeJS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/bin/materialize.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script('palpaJS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/palpa.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'palpa_script_enqueue');
```

//code in palpa.js which requires jquery

```
jquery(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slider').slider();
    });
```

//error in browser console
[image]

//sources directory
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slider();
});
```

Note `Q` UPPERCASE

Comment: Wonderful, that solved the issue, I completely missed that. Thank you so much for the help. I will remember to look out for the case in future.

Comment: Would appreciate any other tips regarding the code above if anything seems out of place? regarding using "jQuery" instead of the "$" sign do i have to replace it in each instance?

Comment: You can use it like this: `(function( $ ){ /*here you can use '$' sign*/ })( jQuery );`

Comment: Ah I see, This makes complete sense now. Thank you again very much for your kind help!